# mergExt - What are the best practices to speed up the creation of control with mergAVCamCreate

Tags: video-capture, livecode

What are the best practices, if any, to speed up the creation of control with mergAVCamCreate?

Thank you

PS
And would be great also to know when the control is created to abilitate the other buttons. Maybe this could be done by just adding lines under the CamCreate command I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any really although you could reduce the time the user thinks it takes by getting the view setup before it's presented then just setting it's visible.

Comment: Thank you Monte, is there a way to know when the view is ready to be presented (created)?

Comment: Too bad, I was thinking of using this information to enable the recording buttons. No matter, I'll find another solution. I hope...

Comment: Is there the possibility to use the external mergBgTask to avoid to call mergAVcreate every time user come back to the app? I ask this because I want to speed up the use of the app by the user.

Comment: mergBgTask won't help here but you could experiment with removing the exits on suspend plist key

Comment: Thank you so much Monte. It seems to work great, to have the app ready for recording now is really fast. I expect to find some downside, for now, I do not know (of course I know that there will be some reason if this mode is not supported) but for now everything seems ok.